# Conditions in a FOR loop

Tags: c++

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void numberChecker();
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess);
int main(){
    numberChecker();
    return 0;
}

void numberChecker(){
    int num;
    int guess = false;
    cout << "Hello, welcome to my program!\nGuess: ";
    for ( ; numberCalc(num, guess==false); ){
        cin >> num;
    }
}

bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
    return guess = 1;
}
```

If I have a for loop, and the condition is looking at a method such as `numberCalc(num, guess)`, how can I, in the for loop, check the `guess` argument and ignore `num`?

And also, let's say I want to compare for example `num == 0` and `guess == true`, how do I lay that out?

```
for ( ; numberCalc(num == 1, guess==false) ;
```

Comment: So you want `numberCalc()` to return true if `num` is 0 and `guess` is true? You might want to add some more lines on the expected behavior.

Comment: You should re-indent your code. I don't what you mean when saying "ignore num" because you're already ignored num in your numberCalc function

Comment: I've correctly indented the code (as soon as the edit is accepted, of course). @Shadwell For future reference `tab` does not work. Use `4 spaces`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to terminate yor loop when num=0 and guess=false, you may define `numbercalc` as:

```
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
return guess || num ;
}
```

Or better use a while loop

```
while(guess||num) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
return guess = 1;
}
```

the last `return guess = 1;` line assigns 1 to `guess`, and return the result of that assignment, so it always returns 1. You should change it to

```
return guess == 1;
```

Comment: what's wrong with this? Or just a dumb downvote?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only about `guess` you can always write:

```
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
return guess == someValue; // value with you want to campair
}
```

If you write the function like :

```
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
    return guess = someValue; // value with you want to campair
    }
```

It'll return the result of the assignment operation ( which is likely to be true always)
If you want to check both condition you can write like:

```
bool numberCalc(int num, bool guess){
return guess==someValue1 || num==someValue2 ;
}
```